# How do you invoke a multi-line shell command in swift?

Tags: swift, shell, sed

How can I invoke a multiline `sed` command in a Swift script? As in my use of `sed` in the example below:

```sh
$ cat test.txt
line 1

line 3
$ sed -i '' '2i\
we are the new 2' test.txt
$ cat test.txt  
line 1
we are the new 2
line 3
```

I've tried the following (note that `/absolute/path/to/file` is the absolute path to a file):

```swift
let task = Process()
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments = ["""
    sed -i '' '2i\\
    we are the new 2' /absolute/path/to/file
    """]
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
```

And I get the following output:

```
env: sed -i '' '2i\
we are the new 2' /absolute/path/to/file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Invoke an *executable* script starting with `#!/bin/sed`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, that would solve it, but then I may as well write my entire script in shell. I'm looking for a solution that lets me stay in Swift.